# Is there a way to set a theme for the input decoration prefix icon?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an input field which has a prefix Icon, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the theme for when the field is not selected. This is what it looks like when not selected

[image]

As you can see the icon has a dark color while it should have the light color that the border has. When I select the field I get this

[image]

Which is much better because now I can actually see the icon. The documentation says

```
The size and color of the prefix icon is configured automatically using an [IconTheme] and therefore does not need to be explicitly given in the icon widget.
```

But when I set the icon themes

```
iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: _primaryColorLight),
primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: _primaryColorLight),
accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: _primaryColorLight),
```

Nothing changes?

```
  Widget _buildNameField(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return TextFormField(
      onSaved: (String value) => _phoneNumber = value,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      style: theme.textTheme.body1,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
        hintText: 'Name',
      ),
      validator: (String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 2) return 'Please enter a name with two letters or more';
      },
    );
  }
```

That's my name field. Now I could ofcourse just give the icon a color. But I so happen to be using a package which has a selection menu which also uses a TextFormField and also faces the same problem. So I could ofcourse fork that repo and change the icon color in there aswell. But that seems way to much effort and pretty hacky.

So how can I set it with a theme?

**Edit**

The documentation says that the TextFormField's prefix icon theme comes from a IconTheme.

```
return IconTheme(
  data: theme.iconTheme,
  child: ListTileTheme(
    iconColor: theme.iconTheme.color,
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: TheRootPage(),
      theme: theme,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
  ),
);
```

This works for the ListTileTheme but not for the IconTheme why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to add this to your theme data `brightness: Brightness.dark,` and `brightness: Brightness.light,` depending on your background color.

Comment: I have set brightness but it still doesn't work for me for an unknown reason